# Trouble with using a php array in SQL WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, arrays, oracle

I have a sql statement in my php page that looks like this:

```
 $places=array('CHI','DET','LA','NYC','DALLAS');

$SQL="SELECT NAME,
             ID,
             PHONE,
             EMAIL,
             LOCATION
      FROM SHOPPERS
      WHERE LOCATION IN '{$places}'
      AND ID BETWEEN '25687' AND '28050'
      ";
```

Then I'm echoing out the query as a table, but I'm not getting any results because there's a problem with the $places array. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format it to be friendly with what SQL expects:

```
$places=array('CHI','DET','LA','NYC','DALLAS');

$SQL="SELECT NAME,
             ID,
             PHONE,
             EMAIL,
             LOCATION
      FROM SHOPPERS
      WHERE LOCATION IN ('".implode("', '", $places)."')
      AND ID BETWEEN '25687' AND '28050'
      ";
```

SQL `where column in` clauses need brackets around them, so you need to add them in - and then you still need to implode the array into a string. The constructed SQL should look like this:

```
$SQL="SELECT NAME,
             ID,
             PHONE,
             EMAIL,
             LOCATION
      FROM SHOPPERS
      WHERE LOCATION IN ('CHI','DET','LA','NYC','DALLAS')
      AND ID BETWEEN '25687' AND '28050'
      ";
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried implode earlier, but I guess I didn't have the right apostrophes.